# How to deal with progressBar on a PyQt4 function?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'd like to know how to represent on a progressBar what kind of percentage of a function is done, because cannot deal with it with a the method setValue().

e.g: I'm searching on a DB and need to represent the percentage got on DB meanwhile the searching still goes on.

Thank you very much

Comment: You must pass the percentage of the search with respect to the total of options, that information is not obtained by QProgressBar, for example let's say that I am looking for a word in 100 files, then the value would be the number of files where I already search.

Comment: If the DB does not report its current progress, there is no "percentage" to represent.